# Use local transformed appsettings.json, but exclude it from deployment to Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, appsettings, azure-deployment, slowcheetah

When using SlowCheetah to transform `appsettings.json` you must use the option to `Copy to Output Directory` for the transforms to actually be transformed.

This works just fine during local testing. The `appsettings.json` is transformed and copied to the output directory. However, for deploying to Azure you don't want to publish any `appsettings.json` files (as the values will be read from the App Service's configuration), and seeing as the file is actually copied to the output directory it seems to follow that it would also be copied to Azure.

How can I use the SlowCheetah transforms locally, while at the same time not deploying them to Azure?

Comment: When you test local you could set Copy to Output Directory and when you deploy why don't set it to Do not copy?

Comment: The .csproj is what defines if files are copied or not. We can't have different .csproj files for local development and devops deployment (I mean, we could, but we don't want the extra maintenance)